# session not working after page redirect to dashboard

Tags: php, session

Login page is not working due to session problem after direct to dashboard page.

```
       $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_details[0]['id'];
       $_SESSION['currentid'] = $user_details[0]['id'];
       $_SESSION['admin_username'] = $user_details[0]['user_name'];
       $_SESSION['admin_status'] = $user_details[0]['user_role'];
       $_SESSION['user_role'] = $user_details[0]['user_role']; 
       header("location:dashboard.php");
```

Session value working before this redirect,but dashboard.php file have below code and there i am not able to get session value.Even session is enabled in server also in default.

```
include ("../includes/config.inc.php"); 
$objAdmin = new Admin();
$objAdmin->Admin_authetic();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5aWH.png

Can anyone give solution for this issue?

Comment: use session_start(); before set session value and dashboard.php

Comment: Make sure you have `session_start()` at the top of the page...

Comment: I have added at first line session_start(),it not worked.

Comment: Make sure the `$user_details[0]['x']` is right and returning the correct value

Comment: yeah,I checked session value by print code before redirect.

Comment: saved session.save_path = /tmp this code in php.ini file and uploaded in public_html folder,issue solved

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `session_start()` at the dashboard.php

Comment: I have added at first line session_start(),it not worked.